# Query Task.Who.Owner.Email in SOQL

Tags: soql, leads, tasks, lead-owner

I what to write a soql to query the user email address but failed to do so.

Basically from a task, I want to find its related lead(WhoID) then find the lead owner, then find the owner's email.

my query look like this

```
List<Task> myTasks = [SELECT Id,
                            WhoId,
                            Who.Owner.Email
                     FROM   Task
                     WHERE  Id = :myLeadIds];
```

Salesforce does not recognize the 'Owner relationship' and I dont understand why.

I tried:

```
List<Task> myTasks = [SELECT Id,
                             WhoId,
                             Who.Email
                      FROM   Task
                      WHERE  Id = :myLeadIds];
```

Which is not the email I wanted but salesforce does not prompt error so I assume it proved that it can recoginze the 'who' relationship, so I dont understand why the
'Owner' lookup field is not recognized while the Email field is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WhoId` and `WhatId` on the `Task` SObject are polymorphic relationship fields.

They can hold an Id (just one Id) from a variety of different SObjects, so the standard way of querying/accessing parent data doesn't work.

You could simply gather the `whoId` from your tasks and use that to feed a second query (e.g. `[SELECT Owner.Email FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :taskWhoIdList]`), and put the result into a map. You could then iterate over your `Task` records, and `myLeadMap.get(task.WhoId);`

The other option is a feature Salesforce gave us a few releases ago (ok, a bit further back than I realized. This looks like it was released back in Winter '13), allowing us to [work with ploymorphic relationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm) in a single query. (The [documentation from the SOQL/SOSL guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm) is probably a better reference here).

Using that, your query would look something like
`[SELECT TYPEOF Who WHEN Lead THEN Owner.Email END FROM Task WHERE Id IN :taskIdList]`

You'll still get a `List<Task>` from the query, and you'd use `instanceOf` to ensure you only try to access Lead data when `WhoId` points to a Lead.

```
for(Task t :taskQuery){
    if(t.Who instanceOf Lead){
        system.debug(t.Who.Owner.Email);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could add in `Type` along with `TYPEOF` in the same query to eliminate the need for filtering afterwards - `WHERE Who.Type IN ('Lead')`